# exact differential equation and multiplicator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

Let $P^2+Q^2\gt 0$ ,$P_x=Q_{y'}$ and $P_y=-Q_{x'}$ then proof that the equation

$$P(x,y)+y'Q(x,y)=0$$

has the multiplicator $(P^2+Q^2)^{-1}$

I dont understand whats meant by $Q_{x'}$ or$P_x=Q_{y'}$ . $P_x$ is the partial derivative with respect to x and  is $Q_{x'} =\frac{d^2}{d^2x}Q$
 ?

Has anyone seen that particular Notation because I havent.

Would appreciate an Explanation.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't misread normal commata? The equations look like the usual Cauchy-Riemann PDE for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Looked at it again.  If your right its probably printing mistake